# Set a timeout to maven downloading resources?

Tags: maven

I don't want maven to download from any repository...is there a way to set download time out from all the repository?

The offline tag set to "true" in settings.xml is helpless in this case.

Comment: Hm. You don't won't to go offline but you want to set the time-out to infinity. Can you please elaborate a little bit more to see what you like to achieve?

Comment: am trying to use Hudson, build a maven project with it. Its on a server where downloading is not possible. So, want to not even try for that.

Comment: Don't you have a repository manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `mvn` with the `-o` flag will stop Maven downloading dependencies from remote repositories.

e.g.:

```
mvn -o install
```

Comment: am trying to use Hudson, build a maven project with it. Its on a server where downloading is not possible. So, want to not even try for that...I can't execute this command. Though this works very fine on my local machine.